# Displaying all sub categories of parent category on sub category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.2.2

I am using Magento CE 1.9.2.2 what I am trying to do is
I have category structure like the below

```
- Party
     - Balloons
     - Bags
     - Streamers
```

Now if you click on the category "party" on the left side Magento shows the "browse by" category/sub category list. However if I click on Balloons I want the same browser by block to be displayed so that even when you are on a sub category page you will be able to see the links to the other sub categories in the left side column in a browser by box.

Hope this is clear what I want to achieve because I am not able to get anything to be displayed on the sub categories?  So what I have done is in Magento manage categories I went to the "balloons" category and changed Display Mode to static block and products. I then changed the drop down CMS Block and selected the block I made called Sub Category Listing.

Then in my Sub category listing block I added the below in code view
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/subcategory_listing.phtml"}}

I then opened ftp and created the subcategory_listing.phtml and added the below code

```
       $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
       $_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
       $_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
           ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
           ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
           ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
           ->joinUrlRewrite();
     ?>

     <div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing">
          <ul id="subcats" class="clear">
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                <?php Mage::log($_category->debug(), null, 'mylogfile.log'); ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="subcat clearfix">
                        <a class="now-from-container" href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>"></a>
                        <div class="subcat-image">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" width="190" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subcat-title-container">
                            <h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code to get the children categories from current category, which looks like this :

```
<?php
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
        ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
        ->joinUrlRewrite();
?>
```

Try with this code instead :

```
<?php
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($_category->getAllChildren(true))
        ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
        ->joinUrlRewrite();
?>
```

Difference is, your call to method `getChildren` returns a comma separated list of IDs, not an array, while the method `addIdFilter` expects an array to be passed. When you pass true to the method `getAllChildren`, it will return the list as an array.

Comment: Thank you Prateek, I tried the change you listed but that did not do anything?

Comment: @user1739740, check with `var_dumo($_category)`, if it contains anything at all.

Comment: I did a var_dump($_category) as well as var_dump($_categories) and both do not display anything to the page. So not sure where to go from here?

Comment: Well, then either you are not on a category page or that category is not set as anchor in admin. Check both of these.